# Google Cloud error 13: An internal error occurred when running gcloud app deploy in console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Recently I added a friend to my project and gave her Owner, App engine admin, app engine deploy rights but when she tries to publish her changes and make a current version she gets error 13: An Internal error occurred.

She runs the command gcloud app deploy.

Can someone help us?

[image: Image with permissions]

[image: Image with console that shows error]

Comment: Can you provide more info? app.yaml file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a default app.yaml configuration, and then, if ok, put your config line per line.